# Pandas read_csv function : is there a way to read specific column as string based on index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv containing data as below:

```
identifier,vcenter,cores,ram
008,10.196.15.190,4,8
```

When I read the csv file, it reads the identifier as int

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('vm.csv')
df
    identifier  vcenter cores   ram
    8   example123  4        8
```

What i require:

```
identifier  vcenter cores   ram
 008       example123   4        8
```

It is not always sure the identifier column name will be named identifier, it can be "machine_name", "identifiers_example". So I cant use specify dtype using column name.

I used dype=object , but it changes the datatype for all columns including cores and ram. This is caught in code validation part so cant use it. However the index of identifier is always known, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is "identifier" column or "machine_name" or whatever always the first column? if yes, then you can use the column number instead of specifying the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert the first column into `str` you can use :
`df.iloc[:,0]=df.iloc[:,0].astype(str)`

or when you read the csv : `pd.read_csv(...,dtype = {0:str})`